# OS X console app - cannot read the arguments

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, console, console-application

On a simple application for the console I can not read the arguments

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(path, argv[1]);
printf("arguments %d\n", argc);
....
```

Always argc is 1

Runing the application from the console it's like this:

```sh
open mytestconsoleapp --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Always argc is 1. It's weird to me.

I don't understand why, what's the problem?

Comment: `strcpy(path, argv[1]);` How can you be sure `argv[1]` is large enough to hold all the chars in `path` (whatever that is)?

Comment: Why `open` in the front of your command?

Comment: Are you writing this in `C` or `C++`? Currently it looks like you're using `C`

Comment: please show a [mre], I can't get `open` to run a command line program on my machine

Comment: Or, just don't specify a decimal output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if you're actually writing `C++` and not `C`.

```
static std::string path;

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] ) { 
    // With either solution you should make sure that the passed in 
    // argument isn't gigantic.
    if ( argc > 1 ) { 
        path.assign( argv[ 1 ] );
        std::cout << path << '\n'
    }

    // Or you could use one of the std::string constructors.
    // This is a nice solution if you don't require global state.
    if ( argc > 1 ) { 
        std::string buffer{ argv[ 1 ] };
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
    }
}
```

If however you're doing this in `C` then use:

```
static char path[ 256 ];

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] ) {
    if ( argc > 1 ) { 
        strncpy( path, argv[ 1 ], sizeof( path ) - 1 );
        printf( "%s\n", path );
    }
    
    // Or if you don't need the global variable.
    if ( argv > 1 ) { 
        char buffer[ 256 ] = { 0 };
        strncpy( buffer, argv[ 1 ], sizeof( buffer ) - 1 );
        printf( "%s\n", buffer );
    }
}
```

And then run your application with the following: `./mytestconsoleapp test`

Comment: why make `path` a global variable? globals are bad and not necessary here

Comment: @AlanBirtles Because I'm trying to mimic what I believe the `OP` is using (he didn't show us much). But I 100% agree that global variables are not needed. Ill update the `C` example using a local buffer as well.

Comment: Command line was wrong... I do not understand why it does not work with open, I specify that executable is on another PC, I call it from the network. I used the command line proposed by WBuck and it works. Thanks. The C++ code was ok

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. There is nothing wrong with your program. However, `%d` is the format string for decimal.

I would suggest you try `%s` ?